# Atom comments are incorrect

Tags: php, comments, atom-editor

When I toggle comments in PHP with Atom, it always comment as HTML, even if the file extension is PHP. Example :

```
<!-- <?php echo "Test"; ?> -->
```

instead of

```
// <?php echo "Test"; ?>
```

Is there a way to fix that? I tried in atom --safe mode, but it doesn't help. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Atom do you use ? Do you have some packages installed, like Emmet ? It can be found on internet that this package can cause described problems ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; that is normal as you haven't opened your php code yet.   If you wanted to comment in php it would be like this:  `<?php // echo "Test"; ?>`

Comment: Because when the cursor is outside the `<? ?>` or `<?php ?> editor believes he has in the space of html - and this is the correct behavior. If you want to comment PHP code - do it inside the `<?php ?>`.

Comment: If I toggle comment in Sublime for example, it will comment like this : // <?php echo "Test"; ?>

Comment: Emmet is not installed. I've just downloaded Atom, it's version 1.0.2

Comment: @stdob-- Even if it's a line without <? ?>, it comments in HTML way.

Comment: No, you need inside `<? ?>` scope.

Comment: @stdob-- In Sublime and Netbeans, we can select all line to comment and it will put // at the beginning. I guess I will have to deal with that and comment in <?php ?>.

Comment: @NancyLussier Yes, you need select line inside <?php ?> to comment in PHP style.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a normal behaviour. Because all around php tags is html code.

Comment: Can I change this behaviour to always comment lines as // ?